# Python eve - How to access before update data in PATCH on_update_resource hook

Tags: python, hook, eve

When updating a document in python eve, like `PATCH /resource_name/item_id`. I want to get the data before updating the document.

What should I do in the hook function (on_update_resource)？

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

when you create your `on_update_<resource_name>` hook, the second parameter will have the original document. You can check whatever you want in it. The function signature is as follows.

```
def event(updates, original)
```

Documentation is here (http://python-eve.org/features.html#database-event-hooks)